# Regex pattern discriminating between letters when it shouldn't?

Tags: java, regex

I'm writing a regex for a simple username validation for practice. While I am sure there may be other issues with this pattern, I would like it if someone could explain this seemingly odd behavior I am getting.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class userRegex{
   public static void main(String[] args){
      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      int testCases = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
      while(testCases>0){
         String username = in.nextLine();
         String pattern = "([[:alpha:]])[a-zA-Z_]{7,29}";
 Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
         Matcher m = r.matcher(username);

         if (m.find( )) {
            System.out.println("Valid");
         } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid");
         }
         testCases--;
      }
   }
}
```

When I input:

```
2
dfhidbuffon
dfdidbuffon
```

the compiler should return:

```
Valid
Valid
```

but instead, it returns

```
Valid
Invalid
```

Why does it discriminate between the difference of the 3rd letter being "h" or "d" in each of the usernames?

Edit: Added @Draco18s and @ruakh 's suggestions, however, I am still getting the same strange behaviour.

Comment: My guess is that `dfdidbuffon` has an end of line character which is not matching the regex.  In other words, the one letter difference is not responsible for what you are seeing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen No, the behavior is actually as indicated. I've tried it with various combinations, orderings, and counts. Something is wacky.

Comment: According to Regexpal.com "([:alpha:])" is matching "all of the characters ':','a','h','l','p'.  "dfdidbuffon" does not see any of those characters, so it fails (the [a-Z] portion is never reached).

Comment: OP: A couple of notes that would make this much easier to read: Compile static patterns outside the loop (they're thread-safe and can be made into constants) and use a `for` loop when you have a counter condition.

Comment: @Draco Write it up as an answer; that's a good catch. I suggest including the value of `^$`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`[:alpha:]` doesn't have the special meaning that you intend; rather, it ends up just meaning "any of the characters `:`, `a`, `h`, `l`, `p`". So `dfhidbuffon` contains a match for your pattern (namely `h` plus `idbuffon`), whereas `dfdidbuffon` does not. (Note that `matcher.find()` looks for any match *within* the string; if you want to specifically match the *entire* string, you should use `matcher.matches()`, or you can modify your pattern to use anchors such as `^` and `$`.)

You may be thinking of the notation found in many regex implementations whereby `[:alpha:]` means "any alphabetic character"; but firstly, Java's `Pattern` class doesn't support that notation (hat-tip to [ajb](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2464386/ajb) for pointing this out), and secondly, those languages would require `[:alpha:]` to appear *inside* a character class, e.g. as `[[:alpha:]]`. The Java equivalent would be `\p{Alpha}` or `[A-Za-z]` if you only want to match ASCII letters, and `\p{IsAlphabetic}` if you want to match any Unicode letter.

Comment: Good catch, I didn't know that. However, I am still experiencing the same strange behaviour.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I would use that, however I do not want to allow digits in the usernames.

Comment: I don't see anything in the `Pattern` javadoc (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) that says that `[[:alpha:]]` has any special meaning.  Are you sure this works in Java?  Or are you thinking of some other language?  Java does have `\p{Alpha}`.

Comment: @ajb Yep, that seems to be the problem. That still leaves me with the question, why would it respond to the first as valid, if neither of them matched [[:alpha]]?

Comment: @user2533660 Because you didn't tell the matcher to match the _entire_ string.  The way you wrote it, it will return true if any substring matches, and in the first case, `"hidbuffon"` matches because `h` is one of the characters in "alpha".  To test whether the _entire_ string matches the pattern, put `^` at the front of the pattern and `$` at the end.

Comment: @ajb Ah, I see! This answers the last of my questions. Thanks.

Comment: Just because [:alpha:] behaves this way in a given regex implementation doesn't mean that your answer is canonically correct.   Do you have a reference showing that this is defined behaviour for Pattern?

Comment: @DSJustice: I don't really understand your question. How else could `[:alpha:]` possibly behave, while still conforming to the specification at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html?

Comment: @ruakh: The way you worded the first paragraph of your answer led me to believe that you were saying that [:alpha:] has a special meaning in Pattern matching that particular set of characters.  I would've gotten it if you'd just said it had no special meaning, did not match a Posix character class, and was just a different way to write the character class [ahlp:].

Comment: @DSJustice: Fair enough. I've made it more explicit now.

Answer (score 1):

:Alpha: is shorthand for the Posix character class of alphabetic characters.

According to the [Java 7 "Pattern" docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), Posix character classes are supported using the `\p{Alpha}` format, not the :alpha: format -- the latter format is not listed anywhere in the reference.

It works as expected for me with the pattern definition using the supported format for the Posix character class definition as follows:

```
String pattern = "(\\p{Alpha})[a-zA-Z_]{7,29}";
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Regexpal.com "([:alpha:])" is matching "any of the characters ':','a','h','l','p'". "dfdidbuffon" does contain any of those characters, so it fails (the [A-z] portion is never reached).

You probably intended `"[a-zA-Z](\\w){7,28}"`  If using regex notation directly, `/[a-zA-Z](\w){7,28}/`

This would match any 'alpha' character, then 7 to 28 word characters (alphanumeric + underscore)

If you don't want numbers, then `"[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z_]){7,28}"`

Comment: Doesn't `[A-z]` match a number of punctuation characters that he might not want?

Comment: @ajb No, it does not.  Feel free to check it for yourself. http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=96273

Comment: `\w` should be `\\w` in java

Comment: I have confirmed in a Java program that `[A-z]` matches the characters `[`, `]`, backslash, `^`, `_`, and backtick.  I don't know what this regexpal.com site is, but either it's giving you wrong answers or you're not using it correctly.  `[A-z]` does not match *only* letters.  Period.

Comment: regexpal.com says the same thing.  Try a string starting with one of those punctuation characters.

Comment: so it should be `[A-Z|a-z](\\w){7,28}` ?

Comment: @ScaryWombat No, just `[A-Za-z]`.  The way you wrote it, the pattern would match a `|` character at the beginning.  `|` has no special meaning inside character classes.

Comment: Oh right, that part was for the *first* character.  Whoops. Thanks @ajb  I use RegexPal because I'm not that good at parsing it in my head.